# Send Mail using Java Mailer API and Actor

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I am building application that use java mailer api to send mail in play 2.4. Now i want to make this service asynchronous and non blocking. **What is the best practice to implements asynchronous and non blocking**? I found some example in scala but i want to implement in java.  I have implemented mailer service using actor model but i am getting error. Below is my code

```
 public class MailerActor extends UntypedActor {
    MailerClient mailerClient;
    @Inject
    public MailerActor(MailerClient mailerClient) {
        System.out.println("inside MailerActor constructor");
        this.mailerClient = mailerClient;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof NewRequest) {
            Email email = new Email();
            email.setSubject("Activation Link");
            email.setFrom("rec@gmail.com");
            email.addTo("receiver@gmail.com");
            email.setBodyText("hello");
            mailerClient.send(email);
        }

    }
    public static Props props(final MailerClient mailerClient) {
        return Props.create(new Creator<MailerActor>() {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
          @Override
          public MailerActor create() throws Exception {
            return new MailerActor(mailerClient);
          }
        });
      }
}
```

I am calling this actor using below code

```
 class Controller {
    @Inject MailerClient mailerClient;
        final ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create();
        final ActorRef mailerActor = actorSystem.actorOf(MailerActor.props(mailerClient));

public Result sendMail(){ 
    NewRequest newRequest = new NewRequest();
    mailerActor.tell(newRequest, mailerActor);
    return ok("done");
}
```

and below is my confg

```
play{
  modules {
    enabled += "play.api.libs.mailer.MailerModule"
    #enabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"
    #enabled += "play.api.db.HikariCPModule"
  }

  mailer {
      host=smtp.gmail.com
      port=465
      ssl=yes
      tls=no
      user="sender@gmail.com"
      password="axy"
      debug=yes
  }
}
```

i am getting following exception

```
[ERROR] [03/19/2016 21:20:54.473] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://default/user/$a] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at actors.MailerActor.onReceive(MailerActor.java
```

Comment: I doubt that the underlying mail library is asynchronous. So you are essentially blocking the actor. You could of cours have multiple instances of that actor, but it's still that blocking call.

Comment: Yes, actor could be block but here i am using actor.tell pattern because i don't want any response from actor. Once i will send request to actor i can do other work in controller. But i don't know best way to implement this service

Comment: Do you get the NPE on the line where you call 'mailClient.send'? If so, then I guess you have an issue with dependency injection in your controller. Please make sure that works.. From my scala-knowledge, I guess the rest should work out fine.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace. Right now the problem looks to be related more to the dependency injection setup than to Akka